# Listing Custom Element bindings in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

Is there a way to get a list of all the binding property names on a custom element without resorting to the Polymer object's properties?

```
<custom-element foo="{{bar}}" baz="{{qux}}"></custom-element>
```

The above should have a list, bindings/properties, of value:

```
["foo", "baz"];
```

Comment: `[foo, bar]` or `[foo, baz]`?

Comment: `[foo, baz]` fixed in the OP

Comment: Interesting question. Out of curiosity, why do you need this information?

Comment: I'm creating a wrapper component that will dynamically load other custom components based on a outside config file.  I need to have a list of the bindings to the wrapper component in order to create bindings on the dynamic component.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all of the properties that are defined on the Polymer element with `element.properties`.

Lets say we have a following `Polymer` definition:

```
Polymer({
  is: "x-element",
  properties: {
    foo:{
      type: Object
    },
    baz:{
      type: Object
    }
  }
});
```

And it has been included in the html file as:

```
<x-element id="x" foo="{{bar}}" baz="{{qux}}"></x-element>
```

To get the propreties we can do the following:

```
var xElemProperties = document.querySelector('#x').properties;
```

That will contain all of the properties. Property doesn't need to be set a value on the `<x-element>` to be found with this. If you only want to get the properties that have been set on the `<x-element>`. You can compare the `.properties` array to the 'element.attributes' array. `.attributes` will contain all of the properties that have been set on the element. It will also contain `id` and other fields like that.

Demo (look into the browsers console):

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!---- >
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  Toggle below/above as backup when server is down
  <!---->
  <base href="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

  <template>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function(){
      Polymer({
        is: "x-element",
        properties: {
          foo:{
            type: Object
          },
          baz:{
            type: Object
          }
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>

</dom-module>

<x-element id="x" foo="{{bar}}" baz="{{qux}}"></x-element>
<x-element id="z"></x-element>

<script>
  var xElemProperties = document.querySelector('#x').properties;
  console.log(xElemProperties);
  var zElemProperties = document.querySelector('#z').properties;
  console.log(zElemProperties);
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: One of the requirements is that the properties must be gathered without knowing the property names beforehand.  So in this case, foo and baz can be passed into <x-element> without foo and baz being set as properties of the <x-element> prototype.